# Route53 recored from multiple ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

I'm getting  `[ERR]: Error building changeset: InvalidChangeBatch: [FATAL problem: UnsupportedCharacter (Value contains unsupported characters) encountered with ' ']`

when trying to create aws_route53_record using Terraform.

I have a .tf file which creates 3 ec2 instances using `count` and I want to create an A record for each instance using Route53.

My aws_route53_record code looks like this:

```
  count   = "3"
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.name.zone_id
  name    = "consul-server ${count.index +1}"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = ["${element(var.consul, count.index)}"]
```

`var.consul` is a variable which contains the ec2 instances IPs, an `output` from a different module.
The output looks like this:

```
Consul-Servers = [
  "10.10.1.217",
  "10.10.1.131",
  "10.10.1.62",
]
```

I'll be glad to get some answers,
Thanks

Comment: The error message strongly implies that your `var.consul` is a list of empty strings.

Comment: There's no need to use `$` anymore, update your syntax style. Count value is integer. Also in *name* you have blank space, and I would go `name = format("consul-server%d", count.index)`.